# QGIS: Can I delete a feature's geometry and keep its table entry?

Tags: qgis

From an original table of rushed and inaccurate polygons representing geofences around some facilities, I am making another shapefile of appropriately quality-checked polygons. I'm doing this by copying each original polygon into the "final copy" layer and editing the vertices to be accurate.

I came across a polygon representing a facility which no longer exists according to aerial data. It has been leveled to the ground in the past couple of years. I need to copy the attributes into the final layer so that I can leave a note on why it has been deleted, but I can't find a way to keep the table entry when there is no geometry attached to it. Is there any way to keep the table entry and remove the polygon?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this was easier than expected-

**Simply deleting all of the vertices** will do exactly this. I was expecting it to be much more technical.